# parse / count in mysql from a string like “09 - 10 10 - 11 11 - 12”

Tags: mysql

I would need to parse in mysql a string like “09 - 10    10 - 11    11 - 12”   Such that i can count how many hours were selected... here the final answer would be 3. The parsing function should also be able to deal with strings like “09 - 10    14 -15    15 - 16    20 - 21” and realize that this is 4 hours.

Comment: And what have *you* tried so far?

Comment: Very bad design. Learn to normalize your data.

Comment: unfortunately this is a string that I get from a reporting system that I cannot alter, so I have to deal with the bad design (and this is not about normalization at all).

Comment: previously I was just parsing the string in excel (which for obvious reasons would like to leave behind). First MID(String, Y ,2) with Y in {1, 6, 9, 14, 17, 22 ...} (steps of 3 and 5 to get rid of the odd spacing);  then newcell=IF(ISNUMBER(valN-valN-1),ValN-ValN-1,0); then SUM all newcells. This works but If fear that the necessary code in mySQL is a lot more complex (and definitely beyond my capabilities at the moment).